# Showing only a `<div>` element, and all its children

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a rather complex HTML page, with a large DOM element tree. For a specified `<div id='mydiv'>`, I would like to hide all DOM elements not contained in `<div id='mydiv'>`, and show all DOM elements contained in (and including) `<div id='mydiv'>`.

The jQuery code I have tried is:

```
$('*').hide();
$('#mydiv').show();
```

but this doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('body > *').hide();   
   $('#mydiv').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/VC5Q6/